# Let $d(n)$ denote the number of positive integers that divide $n$, including $1$ and $n$. Let $f(n)=\frac{d(n)}{n^{1/3}}$

Tags: functions

> Let $d(n)$ denote the number of positive integers that divide $n$, including $1$ and $n$. Let $f(n)=\frac{d(n)}{n^{1/3}}$. There is a unique integer $N$ such that $f(N)>f(n)$ for all $n\not =N$. Find the sum of digits of $N$.

For maxima type questions, the go to method is differentiation. Unfortunately the function isn’t continues, hence it can’t be applied. Another method is by trial and error, but since the options are given for ‘sum’ and not the number itself, the process isn’t possible.

> options: 5,6,7,8,9

Is there any way I can use these options to get the answer. Also what is the proper method for solving? I fear it involves some concept I don’t know, so can I get a hint?

Comment: You might consider the prime factorization of $n$

Comment: @saulspatz yeah but how

Comment: If $n=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\cdots p_k^{a_k}$, what is $d(n)$?

Comment: @saulspatz it is k?

Comment: The number of prime divisors of $n$.

Comment: You should figure out how to compute $d(n)$ from the prime factorization of $n$ as I said before.  $k$ doesn't matter.  How many factors has $2^7\cdot3^9\cdot11^5$?

Comment: @saulspatz oh ok I thought U meant something else.

Comment: @saulspatz I think there is a formula for it, $(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)$. What should I do with it though, $f(n)$ is still inaccessible. I tried setting $f(N+1)<f(N)>f(N-1)$, but it isn’t working

Comment: You can't compare $f(n)$ and $f(n+1)$ because it bounces around too much.  You should be thinking about the shape of the prime factorization.  All numbers of the form $p^2q$ with $p,q$ prime will have $6$ factors from the formula you mention.  Among them, $12$ will have the highest ratio because the numerators are all the same and it has the smallest $n^{1/3}$.  You can just try some small shapes and probably find the right answer.  Then prove that adding in more prime factors decreases the ratio.

Comment: @RossMillikan I get that, but I don’t see an end to that process. I can try $p^2q, p^3q^2, p^3q^2r$ etc. but how will that give me the lowest number. The answer is apparently quite large, and while I may be able to prove it if I knew the answer beforehand, doing it organically looks like a formidable task, unless I am missing some key property here

Comment: The answer has to be a [highly composite number](http://oeis.org/A002182).  I just listed them in a spreadsheet, got the number of divisors from another OEIS entry, computed the fraction, and scanned for the maximum.  Now the task is to prove no larger number has a larger fraction.  You can think about the effect of multiplying by another prime.

Comment: @RossMillikan ok, that does makes sense, but can all this be done on paper, without use of calculators or computers?

Comment: I think it is in range of hand calculation, but it would be a bunch of work.  As I think about it, using the fact that the divisor function is multiplicative can make it easily accessible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we want to solve this completely by hand, the crucial realization is that both the divisor function and the cube root are multiplicative so our function $f(n)$ is, too.  Given any coprime $a,b$ we have $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$.  This allows us to maximize $f(n)$ over the powers of each prime separately, then multiply the results to get $N$.

We have $f(1)=1$.  For any prime $p$, $f(p)=\frac 2{p^{1/3}}$.  For $p \gt 7, p^{1/3} \gt 2$ and we maximize the function at $1$, so $N$ has no prime factors larger than $7$.  Because $7^{1/3} \lt 2, f(7) \gt 1$ and we want a factor of $7$.  On the other hand, $f(49)=\frac 3{49^{1/3}} \lt 1$ so we want exactly one factor of $7$.

At the other end, for $p=2$ we have $f(8)=\frac 42=2, f(16)=\frac 5{2\cdot 2^{1/3}}$.  Since $\frac 54 \lt \frac 1{2^{1/3}}$ (you can cube both sides to see) the maximum comes at $2^3$.

Similar arguments show that we want $3^2$ and $5^1$, giving $N=2^3 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5 \cdot 7=2520$ and the sum of digits is $9$

Comment: Just confirming the process here; for $p=2$, you first found out $f(4), f(8), f(16)$ and proved that $f(4)<f(8)>f(16)$ right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: Thank you so much, excellent answer and excellent explanation too